# Convergence of Borel measure evaluated at sequence of intervals

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\nu$ be a $1$-dimensional Borel measure i.e. for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists an open set $U$ containing $x$ and $\nu (U) < \infty$.

Does $\lim_{\delta \downarrow 0} \nu(a,a+\delta) = 0$ hold for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$? If so why?

Comment: It holds for all $a$.

Comment: Can you please tell me why...

Comment: Continuity of measure from above.

Answer (score 1):

As copper.hat points out in the comments, this is true.  Let $(\delta_n)$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $\delta_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.  By assumpution, there is some open neighborhood $U$ of $a$ such that $\nu(U)<\infty$, hence some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)\subset U$.
There is some $N$ such that $\delta_n<\varepsilon$ for $n\geq N$.  For such $n$, we have 
$$\nu((a,a+\delta_n))\leq\nu((a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon))\leq\nu(U)<\infty.$$
Continuity from above now implies that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\nu((a,a+\delta_n))=0$, and since the sequence $(\delta_n)$ was arbitrary, the result follows.

Comment: Although I know how to show that the conditions on $\nu $ imply continuity from above,)  I dk whether the proposer knows why $\nu$ must be continuous from above.

Comment: I read how to proof continuity from above.

Comment: Although I must say that we dont have $... \subset (a+\delta_{n+2},a)  \subset (a+\delta_{n+1},a) \subset (a+\delta_n,a)$.

Comment: We can show $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \nu((a,a+\delta_{\phi(n)})) = 0$ for some rearrangement $\phi:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ making the $\delta_{\phi(n)}$ monotone. Now any rearrangement of  $ \nu((a,a+\delta_{\phi(n)}))$ will converge to the same limit.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  It is sufficient to assume that $(\delta_n)$ converges monotonically to $0$.